# System Command with Space in R

Tags: r, system, space

I run a system command with spaces in directory name as followed:

```
command=paste(shQuote("java -jar C:/DIR A/DF.jar -t"), t1, t2)
```

I tried also:

```
command=paste('"java -jar C:/DIR A/DF.jar -t"', t1, t2)
```

However I get the following:

```
Error in system(command, intern = TRUE) : 
  '"java -jar C://DIR A/DF.jar -t"' not found
```

How can I handle space in directory name in Windows?

Comment: Try quoting only the dir name `"java -jar 'C:/DIR A/DF.jar' -t"`

Comment: I tried I get  
Warning message:
running command 'java -jar C:/DIR A/DF.jar -t t1 t2 had status 1
And afterwards I have some problems with the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
command=paste('java -jar "C:/DIR A/DF.jar" -t', t1, t2)
```

use " only for the dir name and the outside with '

Comment: Oh, then the opposite of what I said :)