# How to import data file for a Windows executable file from R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Windows executable file from R. I have managed to open the executable file from R using the command:

```
system2('cmd', args=c('/c', '"C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe"'))
```

To run the executable file, I need to import an Excel file by clicking on the button “Load Settings File” (see figure below). Thus, the button is part of the executable file.

[image]

How can I do this from R ?

I have tried this command but it does not work:

```
system2('cmd', args=c('/c', '"C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe"', '"F:/template_LHS1.xlsx"'))

'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
running command '"cmd" /c "C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe" "F:/template_LHS1.xlsx"' had status 1
```

Comment: I guess you can pass the EXE file as cmd arg directly (sorry, no Windows at hand currently to test it): `system2('"C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe"', args=c('"F:/template_LHS1.xlsx"'))`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32541926/4468078

Comment: Yes, the button is part of the EXE file. I have tested the command  `system2('"C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe"', args=c('"F:/template_LHS1.xlsx"'))` but I have the warning message: `had status 127`.

Comment: Try to find out the correct command and arguments on a command line first before trying it with R to find out whether R or your EXE file is causing this error (status 127)

Comment: are you able to run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\UIFormModel.exe" F:\template_LHS.xlsx`?

Comment: Indeed, many Windows EXEs do not have command line execution. One that is named "UIFormModel" sounds like it was intended for use through the User Interface, or on-screen only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points:

- normally one does not have .exe files directly under `C:\Program Files (X86)` so first double check the path name.  I suspect it is not as in the question but is something like the one shown below.
- note the quoting used below
- are you sure that the program accepts a command line argument as an alternative to its GUI?  Can you run it from Windows cmd line? If not you could write an [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com) (see AutoHotKey section below) or [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script to control it and launch that from R.
- if it does accept an argument ensure that the program allows forward slashes -- if not use backslashes

### cmd line argument accepted

If the program accepts a command line argument then try this code:

```
system2("C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel/UIFormModel.exe",  "F:/template_LHS1.xlsx")
```

Another way is:

```
shell('"C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel/UIFormModel.exe" F:/template_LHS1.xlsx')
```

For example, using the free [CSVfix](https://neilb.bitbucket.io/csvfix/) I was able to run the following and found that they worked:

```
system2("C:/Program Files (x86)/CSVfix/CSVfix.exe", "help")

shell('"C:/Program Files (x86)/CSVfix/CSVfix.exe" help')
```

See `?system2` and `?shell` for other arguments you may wish to use.

### AutoHotKey

If the program does not accept command line arguments then this sample AutoHotKey script launches [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), a free file comparison GUI for Windows, comparing the WinMerge executable to itself.  This has the effect of generating a popup warning and the AutoHotKey script dismisses that warning message by sending an Enter keystroke to the WinMerge window.

Be sure AutoHotKey and WinMerge are installed, that the script below is in a text file, test.ahk, in the current directory, the one given by `getwd()`, and then from the R console run:

```
shell("test.ahk")
```

Here is the test.ahk script:

```
exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\winmerge\winmergeu.exe" 
Run %exe% %exe% %exe%
WinWait WinMerge
; dismiss the dialog warning that both files are the same
Send {Enter}
```

If you go this route this script will need to be modified or rewritten in ways that will be specific to your program.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying several alternatives, but I've not successfully called an executable with a parameter. Nevertheless I can suggest a workaround using a .bat file:

```
system2("cmd.exe", input='"D:/workspace/execute.bat"')
```

Where execute.bat may contain something like:

C:/Program Files (x86)/UIFormModel.exe F:/template_LHS1.xlsx